# if and else both are true in my php codes

Tags: php, if-statement, equation

i wonder that both if and it's else are true.

i got $apple_id_num from the input select form and it is a number but in string type like "7" and it is how many ids that user wants.so i convert it to integer

now i want to check if it is not more that what i have available in my database.
but statements under conditions `($num_rows<$id_num)` and if `($num_rows>=$id_num)` both are running.

what i'm doin wrong?

here is my code:

```
function getAppleID($apple_id_num)
{
    $sqli=new mysqlii();
    $apple_ids=$sqli->SelectFromDB($apple_id_num);
    $num_rows=$sqli->num_rows;
    $id_num=(int)$apple_id_num;

    if ($num_rows>=$id_num){
        $this->printAppleID($apple_ids,$num_rows);
        //$sqli->updateRows();
        echo"else if running";
        return $apple_id_num;
   } else if ($num_rows<$id_num)
          echo "if statement was rungning";    
}
```

Comment: actually i do not used return $apple_id_num; because the problem is that i want if ($num_rows>=$id_num) works but it does not it is always true and it's else too.

Comment: can you echo the variables $num_rows and $id_num and check what are their values ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. always write intended code. Sometimes you may miss a `}` :P
Use `elseif` in place of `else if`.

```
function getAppleID($apple_id_num)
{
    $sqli=new mysqlii();
    $apple_ids=$sqli->SelectFromDB($apple_id_num);
    $num_rows=$sqli->num_rows;
    $id_num=(int)$apple_id_num;
    if ($num_rows>=$id_num) {
       $this->printAppleID($apple_ids,$num_rows);
       //$sqli->updateRows();
       echo"else if running";
       return $apple_id_num;
    } elseif ($num_rows<$id_num) {
       echo "if statement was rungning";
    }    
}
```

Comment: the problem if ($num_rows>=$id_num) when its not suppose to be true, it is true for example when (6>= 3) it is still true :'(

Comment: @MitraRzv , if first condition got true, then else part will not be executed anyhow.. i think problem was a missing {.

Comment: i just aded elseif because i wanted to make sure the if is not checking at all. so i add it i got both messeges.